# How can Groupe PSA fly back their French expat employees located at Wuhan back to France despite the ongoing quarantine in Wuhan?

Tags: france, french-citizens, china, health

I read on https://www.20minutes.fr/monde/2703219-20200125-coronavirus-troisieme-cas-confirme-france-15-nouveaux-deces-chine ([mirror](http://archive.is/wip/hDI3m)) that [Groupe PSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupe_PSA) is going to fly back their French expat employees located at Wuhan back to France due to the [Novel coronavirus (2019-nCoV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novel_coronavirus_(2019-nCoV)) epidemic. How can Groupe PSA do so despite the [ongoing quarantine in Wuhan](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/01/22/world/asia/china-coronavirus-travel.html) ([mirror](http://archive.is/Hk1Qd))?

Comment: Maybe they have special permission from the Chinese authorities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chinese goverment are giving special permissions for companies and countries who wishes to evacuate their people / citizens from affected areas.

They will have to be screened of course before being allowed to leave but once cleared and special transport is arranged they are free to leave.

No normal commercial transport is available however so it is chartered planes only at that point from Wuhan.